# Ionic3 FormBuilder bind model values

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a model:

```
export class ProfileModel {

  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public age: number,
    ...
    ...
    ){}

}
```

And I have built a form to update values:

```
<form  [formGroup]="profileForm" (ngSubmit)="updateProfile(profileForm.value)" autocomplete="off">

        <!-- Name -->
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>My name</ion-label>
            <ion-input formControlName="name"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <!-- Age -->    
        <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Age*</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="number" formControlName="age"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>


    ...
    ...

    <button ion-button full type="submit" [disabled]="!profileForm.valid">Update</button>
</form>
```

In my component:

```
export class ProfilePage {

    public profileForm : FormGroup;

  public receievedProfileData: ProfileModel; 

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams, 
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private userService: UserService) {

    this.receievedProfileData= new ProfileModel(null, null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [''],
      age: ['', Validators.required],
      ...
      ...
    });

  }



  ionViewWillEnter(){

    this.userService.getProfile().subscribe(
        data => {
          this.receievedProfileData.name=data.name;
          console.log(this.receievedProfileData)
        },
        error => {

        });

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {


  }

  updateProfile(formData){

    this.userService.updateProfile(formData
      ).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.profileUpdateSuccessMessage="Profile updated successfully!";
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Profile update Error in Profile Page ", error);
      });
    }

  }
```

Right now I see the form with all the fields blank. What I am trying to do is whatever values my user saved last time should be shown on the form i.e. I have to somehow bind them.

I am fetching current profile information from backend and assigning it to *receievedProfileData*. How can I further bind it to the form or the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do, is use `patchValue`, or `setValue` on your `FormGroup` after you recieve the data from the backend.

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.userService.getProfile().subscribe(
    data => this.profileForm.setValue(data)
    // data => this.profileForm.patchValue(data)
  );
}
```

**setValue**

> This method performs strict checks, so it will throw an error if you try to set the value of a control that doesn't exist or if you exclude the value of a control.

**patchValue**

> It accepts both super-sets and sub-sets of the group without throwing an error.

So if your data object mirrors your form object exactly, use `setValue`. 
Otherwise you either have to use `patchValue`, or transform your data object to mirror the form object, before calling the `setValue` method.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Sure just have to wait for another five minutes! You were too fast ;)